# MongoImport with one to one relationship

Tags: mongodb, csv

I have two csv files for cricket stats.

First csv files has these headings:
_id, season, city, date, team1, team2, wonBy

Second csv files has these headings:
macth_id, innings, batting_team, bowling_team, over, ball, batsman, run

Every single record in first csv has some records in second csv with matching match_id, so _id will be equal to match_id.

Now I imported with : `mongoimport -d IPLStat -c iplStats --type csv --file C:\Users\*\Documents\matches.csv --headerline`

Now I need to import the second one which will have a many to one relationship with the first csv imported based on the match_id, so that when I retrieve a match detail it will have data from second csv too, i.e ball by ball details.
How do I achieve this.

Comment: Are you saying you want to import the second file not into a new collection, but as sub-documents (in an array) into the matching documents from the first collection? I think you need to write a program for that.

Comment: Yep, did r&d its not possible from through mongoImport, writing java prog for it. Thanks.